# Putting value in column conditionally

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, case, sql-view

I am trying to create a view in SQL Server as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW HeaquartersSales 
AS
    SELECT
        gs.district,
        gs.MonthToDateSales,
    FROM 
        GlobalSales AS gs
GO
```

However, I only want to put the sales figure in `MonthToDateSales` if district has a "G0-" in its name.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a `CASE` expression:

```
CREATE VIEW HeaquartersSales AS
SELECT
  district,
  CASE WHEN district like '%G0-% THEN MonthToDateSales END as MonthToDateSales
FROM GlobalSales AS gs
GO
```